# How to reuse CWinThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I'm curious about possibilities of reusing `CWinThread`. For example, I have the following class (mutexes and error-checking are omitted):

```
class MyClass
{
    friend UINT ThreadFunc(void* parameter);

public:
    MyClass()
    {
        m_thread                = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc, this, 0, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED);
        m_thread->m_bAutoDelete = false;
    }
    ~MyClass() { delete m_thread; }


    int Value() const { return m_value; }
    void Calculate(int value)
    {
        m_value = value;
        m_thread->ResumeThread();
    }

private:
    CWinThread* m_thread = nullptr;
    int         m_value  = 0;
};

inline UINT ThreadFunc(void* parameter)
{
    auto* mc = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(parameter);
    mc->m_value *= 2;

    return 0;
}
```

1. Is it possible to reimplement the `Calculate` method in the way it would be possible to call it sequentially (currently my class doesn't do calculations after the first call), something like that:

```
MyClass mc;
mc.Calculate(1);
// Waiting for mc to finish...
std::cout << mc.Value() << std::endl;
mc.Calculate(2);
// Waiting for mc to finish...
std::cout << mc.Value() << std::endl;
```

I can only suppose, that it is possible to create somo kind of jobs queue and check it in the loop until thread is stopped.

2. Is it possible to change thread controlling function after the thread had already been created?

Comment: Reusing threads is often a bad idea, unless they were explicitly designed for that.

Comment: "mutexes and error-checking are omitted" - You are specifically asking about threaded code yet you omit locks? Why?

Comment: The question was about reusing a thread, I guessed locks are specifically technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reuse a `CWinThread` object call the constructor (once) and then `CreateThread()` to launch a new (Win32) thread run. Check the documentation. You can either call the `CWinThread` constructor that takes the function address, or instead `AfxBeginThread()` (as youd did) for the very first time and then `CreateThread()` for every (re)run.

It is not possible to change the thread function after it is created, because it stores the address internally, plus there is no method that does this. However, it's quite easy to circumvent this: you pass your `MyClass` object as a parameter and use it in the function, therefore all you need is add a public member to the class and use a case statement in the function.

The way you create your thread is OK, it's a "worker" thread, without a message queue - you should call the other overload of `AfxBeginThread()` to create a thread with a message-queue. FYI, Win32 threads create a message queue on the first `GetMessage()` call, if any.

Some notes:

- The way you demonstrate the use of your object (schedule-wait-print) makes little sense if at all, as you basically serialize the calls - it could have all been run by the main thread with no difference.
- In general I think the `CWinThread` class offers almost no benefits compared to Win32 threads; maybe the auto-delete feature (which you don't use). You can achieve the same by calling the Win32 `CreateThread()` function, and it's a lot more clear and without the overhead of all these objects defined and used internally in `CWinThread`.
- A mechanism you may find interesting, for "submitting tasks" to a server-like "task-queue", is Asynchronous Procedure Calls (APCs). Check the Win32 documentation for details.

---

**EDIT:**
I'm afraid you need to read more about multi-threading and understand better the concepts.

A thread is like an application, in that it has its own program-counter and stack. It runs in parallel with the application's main thread (on a different CPU, CPU core or time-share). And of course an application may launch one or more threads of the same or of a different type, and wait for them to complete or not wait.

The Win32 `CreateThread()` function creates a thread and returns a handle to it; it will finally have to be destroyed by calling `CloseHandle()`. Then you have the MFC `CWinThread` class, which is a wrapper for Win32 threads; contains additional objects for synchronization and control. If `b_mAutoDelete` is `TRUE` the C++ class instance (object) will be deleted when the actual thread completes. The MFC `CWinThread::CreateThread()` member function creates a new Win32 thread for the C++ object. Pls check the documentation incl the Remarks section. So yes, if you set `b_mAutoDelete` to `FALSE` and call `CreateThread()` (after the previous thread terminated) you will have created a new thread, using the same C++ object, ie it IS reused. I can't find benefits in this though, why reuse it really? And why not create multiple threads (for parallel processing) instead of creating them one by one? In your code sample in item 1. you run the thread and then wait for it to complete before running another one. This makes no sense, because everything could have run in the same (main) thread in the same amount of time, as you run all operations one after an other, ie there is no parallelism; and the main thread waits for each of them to complete; then why ever use multhreading?

APCs is a mechanism where a thread can accept "requests" which are placed in a queue, and executed by that (worker) thread. The thread typically remains idle if there are no pending requests (user-mode APC objects in the queue). Not destroyed or terminating, rather waiting for requests to arrive.

---

**EDIT2:**
The (wrong) assumption you made was that the main thread would be waiting for the worker threads to complete - the thread creation functions (`CreateThread()`, `AfxBeginThread()`) instead just create a new thread and return immediately. To make sure that you have mastered it I would suggest that you make another test: create two `MyClass` objects and call `Calculate()` for both (these return immediately too). Then call `WaitForMultipleObjests()` to wait for the completion of both. You will have to make the thread handles public (so you can pass them to the wait function) and I would recommend that you add a delay in `ThreadFunc()` too, eg loop for 5 seconds, so you can test synchronization. As the two threads will be working in parallel, the operation should finish in 5 seconds in total, not 5 + 5. This is not "reusing the thread object" as you had asked, but instead creating multiple threads and waiting for them to complete, which is something that actually does make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you elaborate it a little bit, please? Documentation I've found only says that `CreateThread`, `AfxBeginThread` and similars create NEW threads. So, I can suppose if I use any object, like thread `HANDLE` or `CWinThread`, I have to close previous one (in latter case, I assume I set an `b_mAutoDelete` flag). Hence, it not seems as "reuse". I cannot found any example, where `AfxBeginThread` called for the first time and then reused by `CreateThread()`. Thus, if I'm correct, the only way to reuse thread is APCs?